# WiFi disabled by hardware switch after I poured water on my laptop keyboard

Tags: wireless, hardware

I poured water on my laptop computer. I switched off power and waited for two days. Everything seemed OK except WiFi. It says WiFi is disabled by hardware switch. I tried Fn + Fx, and rfkill unblock all. But nothing works. And also eth0 interface works, but there is no light blinking. Is part of network hardware broken by water. How can I check my network hardware throughly.

```
zw@zw-Inspiron-3442:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

zw@zw-Inspiron-3442:~$ lsmod | grep dell 
dell_laptop            18133  0 
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
wmi                    19177  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

zw@zw-Inspiron-3442:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Thank you. I read dell online manual. There seems no other hardware switch except Fn.  What do you mean by 're-seating and clean contacts' ?

Comment: This comment may sound discouraging, but maybe it will have some use. I had a "hard blocked" wifi on my old Toshiba NB200 (no hardware wifi switch). Never got it resolved in Ubuntu. After a long search I learned I had to install Windows XP and download a tool from Toshiba to enable Fn Key F8 as "hardware switch".

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these two terminal commands: `lsmod | grep dell` and also: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Alban is referring to removing and reinserting the actual card: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fMRtOf6OlQ

Comment: I have tried removing and reinserting  WiFi card. It does not help.  I also find that once I plug in power adapter, my laptop will start itself automatically.   Guess something is damaged by water.

Answer (score 0):

We doubt that you need *both* `dell-wmi` and `dell-laptop` to be loaded. Let's try removing one and see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r dell-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Is there any improvement? If this helps, let's blacklist the module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist dell-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

If it does not help, I will edit my answer to propose another solution.

EDIT: You confirmed that blacklisting dell-laptop did not help. Let's blacklist `dell-wmi` instead.

From the terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line from *blacklist dell-laptop* to instead read:

```
blacklist dell-wmi
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

Is there any improvement?

EDIT 2: Perhaps the airplane mode switch will respond if you remove *both* modules. Since `dell-wmi` is now blacklisted and not loaded, temporarily remove `dell-laptop`. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r dell-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement?

If not, then the only suspicion I have that remains is that the circuitry in the wireless card or in the airplane mode switch has become damaged by the spilled water. I know of no operating system method to correct this.

My last suggestion is to remove the wireless card from the laptop and try a USB wireless device. This post offers some suggestions for finding fully supported, plug and play devices: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573&p=13639455#post13639455

Comment: Blacklisting  dell-laptop does not help. I read /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and find that b43, b43legacy, bcma are all blacklisted. Wish that will help.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Blacklisting dell-wmi instead of dell-laptop still does not help.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I  have tried a USB wireless device of realtek. The USB wireless device is also disabled by hardware switch  both before and after I install driver.  Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is it "disabled by hardware switch" even if you entirely remove the internal device from the laptop?

Comment: No. But after I remove WiFi card from laptop, my USB wireless device works fine.